# KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC duplicates rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC 2016.1.412 grid duplicating data at any update or destroy action. If you click Destroy command it call CREATE action for 10 (ten) times. So if I got 1 row after I destroy it I got 11 row of same data (different ID).
View is like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CETSchoolERP.ViewModels.Administration.StudentsViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.BirthDate).Width(100);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(" "); command.Destroy().Text(" "); }).Width(180);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.StudentID))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Students_Create", "Students"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Students_Read", "Students"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Students_Update", "Students"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Students_Destroy", "Students"))
)
```

)

Controller code

```
public StudentsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: Students
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Students_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(_context.Student.ToList().Select(student => new StudentsViewModel
        {
            FirstName = student.FirstName,
            LastName = student.LastName,
            BirthDate = student.BirthDate,

        }).ToDataSourceResult(request));

    }

    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public ActionResult Students_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel student)
    {
        if (student != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new Student();

            entity.FirstName = student.FirstName;
            entity.LastName = student.LastName;
            entity.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;


            _context.Student.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            student.StudentID = (int)entity.StudentID;
        }

        return Json(new[] { student }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public ActionResult Students_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel student)
    {
        if (student != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var entity = new Student();

            entity.StudentID = student.StudentID;
            entity.FirstName = student.FirstName;
            entity.LastName = student.LastName;
            entity.BirthDate = student.BirthDate;

            _context.Student.Attach(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new[] { student }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public ActionResult Students_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel student)
    {
        if (student != null)
        {
            var entity = new Student();

            entity.StudentID = student.StudentID;

            _context.Student.Attach(entity);

            _context.Student.Remove(entity);

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new[] { student }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

In debug mode any delete or update actions in grid only triggers Students_Create procedure 10 time. Delete or update never called.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the controller code for the Students_Update and Students_Destroy actions? I suspect the issue may be there.

Comment: [Provide something that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)